# node ava, t.context is not available in before test

Tags: javascript, ava

Following the readme, this test should work:

`test.before(t => {
    t.context = 'unicorn';
});`

but it returns back: 
`t.context is not available in before tests`

I expected this to be implemented in the version 0.25, am I doing something wrong?

ava version: "0.25.0"
Node.js v8.9.1
darwin 17.4.0
npm --version 5.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check [this answer](https://github.com/avajs/ava/issues/1728#issuecomment-367659270).

The documentation you see on GitHub relates to version [1.0.0-beta.3](https://github.com/avajs/ava/blob/master/package.json#L3) not to the stable release that was published to [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ava) (which is 0.25.0).

So as you can see for the version `0.25.0` context is available only in `.beforeEach` hook.

If you want to use it in `.before` you gotta install the latest beta:

```
npm i ava@next --save-dev
```